# php function with optional parameters using stdClass

Tags: php, function, parameter-passing, stdclass

Suppose, I have a function such as: [`$data` is a `stdClass()`]

```
function test_1{
    ...
    ...
    if (somecondition){
        $data->name = NULL;
        test_2($data->name);
    }
    else{
        $data->name = 'hello';
        test_2($data->name);    
    }
    ...
    ...
}

function test_2($data){
    if (!empty($data->name)){
        test_3($data->name);
    }
    else{
        test_3();
    }
}

function test_3($s = ''){
    if (!empty($s)){
        //do something
    }
    else{
        $s .= 'World'; 
    }
}
```

`test_3` is the function with optional parameters.
However, I get an error: `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: `test_1` is missing arguments, so this code can't even compile. I suspect you've made other changes while transcribing here, so we can't see the real problem.

Comment: @Barmar: Adding/not adding arguments isn't important in this question. The question was about `test_3`. In any case, I've edited the code. Hope you'll figure it out now. ;)

Comment: You didn't fix `test_1`, it's still missing the parameter list. If `test_1` isn't important, why did you include it?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here. You call `test_2($data->name)`, so `test_2`'s argument `$data` is a string, not an object. But then `test_2()` uses `$data->name`, which should fail because `$data` is not an object in this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you called your function in a manner of the form:

```
$data = new stdClass();
test_3($data);
```

This fails then as you end up in your `else` statement, and you can't concatenate a stdClass() to a string (in this case 'World').

A bit more review suggests that your actual function call is `test_3($data->name)`, and `$data->name` is likely of stdClass() instead of a string that can be concatenated with 'World'.

For reference, if you have an error, it'd be helpful to provide the actual line number the error is corresponding to . . . I'm guessing the error is due to the concat, since that's the only place where I see a stdClass() to string conversion would be necessary.

Comment: In `test_1()`, `$data->name` is set to either `NULL` or a string. So how can it be a `stdClass`?

Comment: @Barmar It seems obvious that this was mainly template code, which is also why when I first answered, I made the assumption that the issue was with test_3() being called with a stdClass object as the argument . . .

Comment: Silly me, when the question shows how `test_3()` is being called, I assume that's relevant to the problem.